# Why does opening a subprocess with universal_newlines cause a unicode decode exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, subprocess

I am using the subprocess module to run a child job, and collecting its output and error streams with subprocess.PIPE's. To avoid deadlock I continually read from those streams on a separate thread.  This works, except sometimes the program crashes due to a decoding issue:

> `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 483: ordinal not in range(128

At a high level, I understand that Python is probably trying to convert to a string using the ASCII codec, and that I need to call decode somewhere, I'm just not sure where. When I create my subprocess job, I specify universal_newlines to be True. I thought this meant, return stdout/stderr as unicode, not binary:

```
self.p = subprocess.Popen(self.command, shell=self.shell, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

The crash happens in my reading thread function:

```
def standardOutHandler(standardOut):
    # Crash happens on the following line:
    for line in iter(standardOut.readline, ''):
       writerLock.acquire()
       stdout_file.write(line)
       if self.echoOutput:
           sys.stdout.write(line)
           sys.stdout.flush()
       writerLock.release()
```

Its not clear why readline is throwing a decoding exception here; as I stated, I thought universal_newlines being true was already returning me decoded data.

What is going on here and what can I do to correct this?

Here is the full traceback

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/lzrd/my_process.py", line 61, in standardOutHandler
for line in iter(standardOut.readline, ''):
  File "/Users/lzrd/Envs/my_env/bin/../lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 483: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: it decodes using whatever is returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding()`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I checked what that function is returning and it does return UTF-8. The system preferred encoding is: UTF-8.

Comment: where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: You might have better luck decoding each `line` yourself, that looks like it may be encoded as latin-1, in python 3 you can also iterate over `stdout` without readline or iter.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Would you be able to elaborate with an answer? Should i not use universal_newlines in my subprocess setup? What does iterating stdout in python3 actually do, if not looking for \n in text mode?  Thanks!

Comment: The docs for `Popen`'s the `universal_newlines` parameter says: `If universal_newlines is True, these file objects will be opened as text streams in universal newlines mode using the encoding returned by locale.getpreferredencoding(False).` I looks like that's returning `ascii` in your case, but the process you're running is outputting text in some other encoding, leading to your decode error. I don't actually know how to fix this, so I'm not posting this as an answer, but I suspect there's some way to tell Python's `locale` system prefer the right encoding.

Comment: Interesten @Blckknght. I tried calling locale.getpreferredencoding with a value of False, just to see what I get back, and I still am getting UTF-8.  If my child process is returning output in an unexpected format like latin-1, I though a huge benefit of UTF was that it was backwards compatible with other encodings like this.

Comment: Is there any way to test what encoding the child process is returning to me? Just to rule that out.

Comment: @darren, remove universal newlines and iterate over stdout using `line = line.decode("latin-1")` and check the output. It should be trying to decode as utf-8 I don't know why it is trying to decode as ascii

Comment: could you post the full traceback if you use Python `io` module: `import _pyio as io, sys; sys.modules['io'] = io`? Or run your script with `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8` and `LC_ALL=C`? e.g., `LC_ALL=C python -m your_module` if you use bash

Comment: if you set  `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')`  do you still get the ascii error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `universal_newlines=True` then the byte stream is decoded into Unicode using `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` character encoding that should be `utf-8` on your system (check `LANG`, `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_ALL` envvars).

If the exception persists; try your code with an empty loop body:

```
for line in standardOut: #NOTE: no need to use iter() idiom here on Python 3
    pass
```

if you still get the exception then it might be a bug in Python if `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is not `ascii` if you check it near `Popen()` call -- it is important to use exactly the same environment here.

I would understand if `UnicodeDecodeError` were showing `utf-8` instead of `ascii`. In that case, you could try to decode the stream manually:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
import locale
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(['command', 'arg 1'], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1) as p:
    for line in io.TextIOWrapper(p.stdout,
                                 encoding=locale.getpreferredencoding(False),
                                 errors='strict'): 
        print(line, end='')
```

You could experiment with `encoding`, `errors` parameters here e.g., set `encoding='ascii'` or use `errors='namereplace'` to replace unsupported characters (in the given character encoding) with `\N{...}` escape sequences (for debugging).

Answer (score 0):

maby is nice:

`process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, encoding='utf-8')
    out, err = process.communicate()
    print('out: ')
    print(out)
    print('err: ')
    print(err)`